# How to convert a list into a dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following list:

```
pet = ['cat','dog','fish','cat','fish','fish']
```

and I need to convert it to a dictionary like this:

```
number_pets= {'cat':2, 'dog':1, 'fish':3}
```

How do I do it?

Answer (score 10):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> pet = ['cat','dog','fish','cat','fish','fish']
>>> Counter(pet)
Counter({'fish': 3, 'cat': 2, 'dog': 1})
```

Answer (score 0):

As @hcwhsa said, you can use `collections.Counter`. But if you want to write your own class, you can start with something like this:

```
class Counter(object):

    def __init__(self, list):

        self.list = list

    def count(self):

        output = {}
        for each in self.list:
            if not each in output:
                output[each] = 0
            output[each]+=1
        return output

>>> Counter(['cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'cat', 'fish', 'fish']).count()
>>> {'fish': 3, 'dog': 1, 'cat': 2}
```